# Using a timer in C

Tags: c, timer

I have read several forums with the same title, although what I am after is NOT a way to find out how long it takes my computer to execute the program.
I am interested in finding out how long the program is in use by the user. I have looked at several functions inside `#include <time.h>`, however, it seems as though these functions (like clock_t) give the time it takes for my computer to execute my code which is not what I am after.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

I have done:

```
clock_t start, stop;
long int x;
double duration;

start = clock();


//code 

stop = clock();  // get number of ticks after loop

// calculate time taken for loop
duration = ( double ) ( stop - start ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf( "\nThe number of seconds for loop to run was %.2lf\n", duration );
```

I receive 0.16 from the program, however, when i timed it I got 1 minute and 14 seconds. how does this possibly add up?

Comment: Yes, there are several different timers and clocks.  You can look at (a) how much CPU time is used or (b) how much time elapsed according to a stopwatch, or a clock on the wall.  (Of course (a) will typically be less than (b), perhaps much less, unless the program is a 100% CPU hog.)

Comment: What is the difference between "how long the program is in use by the user" and "the time it takes for my computer to execute my code"?

Answer (score 2):

The `clock` function counts CPU time used, not elapsed time.  For a program that's 100% CPU-intensive, the time reported by `clock` will be close to wall time, but otherwise it's likely to be less -- often much less.

One easy way of measuring elapsed or "wall clock" time is with the `time` function:

```
time_t start, stop;

start = time(NULL);

// code

stop = time(NULL);  

printf("The number of seconds for loop to run was %ld\n", stop - start);
```

This is a POSIX function, though -- it's not part of the core C standards, and it may not exist on, say, embedded versions of C.

Comment: time() is fairly standard, and is available on windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx).  there are higher precision alternatives, but if you want portable, time() is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [getrusage()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) function. It doesn't give you time consumed like how you use a stop-watch to time a function.

The function gives overall resource usage of the current program and splits it per-user. This is what the [`time`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command gives.